# What does 'It seemed to me, soothed by the elysian air, a Naiad was beside me." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

What does this strange construction mean here?

> It seemed to me, soothed by the elysian air, a Naiad was beside me.

Is this construction possible?

Comment: Though the sentence read fine for me, I think elysian sounds like a proper noun and its e might need to be capitalized.

Comment: @DamkerngT. that's an adjective. No capital required I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction is valid.  Though, it could cause confusion; is the Naiad soothed by the air or is it the narrator? The default interpretation would most likely be the narrator.

The meaning conveys that the narrator believes a female water spirit is near, while the narrator is in a "heavenly" place.  Elysian air implies a paradise or especially nice location.